# mimicking a subsection when publishing

Tags: matlab, publish

I might be wrong, but as far as I understand Matlab does not have a "subsection" option when publishing.

However, if I go for instance [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mkdir.html) (`-mkdir-` documentation), under the *Examples* section there are three "subsections".
How would you obtain this? If it's through HTML only and not through direct Matlab options, is it possible to assign a shortcut or button to create the HTML fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When publishing to html, you can use html-code:

```
%%
% <html>
% <h3>subsection</h3>
% </html>
%
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. About  the second part of the question, do you know whether I can automatically type, say, the above fragment by using a shortcut?

Comment: @Stezzo MATLAB has an option to [Insert HTML Markup](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2008/01/21/marking-up-m-with-html/) to which you can assign a keyboard shortcut in preferences. However, a better approach would be to use use a text expansion tool but recommendations for a tool are off-topic for StackOverflow so you are on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I was looking for: it creates a subsection title the same color of the main title.

```
%%
% <html><h3 style="color:C45400"> 
%       This will produce a Matlab-orange subsection 
% </h3></html>
%
%%
```

Comment: The `<font>` tag is very poor HTML syntax. You should instead use CSS to style (colour) the heading.

Comment: @IKavanagh, I changed the code using CSS, I am note an html expert, but now it should be better.

Comment: The `style` attribute should be on the `<h3>` tag. The extra `<p>` tag is erroneous.

Comment: @IKavanagh Thanks a lot, I edited the answer. Sorry, when you said "text expansion tool" above, you meant an external editor?

Comment: Much better. No I meant a text expansion tool. Some external editors do have the functionality built into them but there are external tools that can work in every program.

Comment: @IKavanagh As a related question, is there a way to add the <h3> level sub-sections into the table of contents?